# Xcode 10 asset catalog Preserve Vector Data not working

Tags: ios, xcasset, asset-catalog, xcode10

My app uses PDF vector assets. Found asset get pixelated scaling in my UIImageView when building my app in Xcode 10 (targetting iOS 11) but when I build same exact app in Xcode 9.4 I do not see this issue and image looks sharp.

[image]

Any ideas for fix in Xcode 10? Note I am still using Beta version, not sure if this is Xcode bug or project bug.

Comment: I have the same issue, I am using Xcode Version 10.1 Someone have a idea how can I solve this problem